# C++ MFC CAnimationCtrl

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I am using C++ MFC `Visual Studio 2022`, and the `CAnimationCtrl`.

I am finding it hard to make use of the control. According to the [CAnimateCtrl Class Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/canimatectrl-class?view=msvc-170).

> The clip must either be uncompressed or compressed with RLE8 compression.

> Run-length encoding (RLE)
> The FOURCC is 'rle ' - note the space [Microsoft_RLE](https://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php/Microsoft_RLE)

I have a GIF file (*a simple spinner*), and I am unable to display it using the control.

I have tried various `GIF` to `AVI` online tools, but I am unable to find the correct tool / settings.

Here is my code I am currently using:

```
if (std::ifstream(L"res\\1488.avi")) {
    BOOL a = loadingCtrl.Open(L"res\\1488.avi"); // a is always 0 for me
    BOOL b = loadingCtrl.Play(0, -1, -1);
}
```

I have tried [libungif](https://github.com/Distrotech/libungif/blob/master/util/gif2rle.c) but this also did not work for me.

I did find these AVI/RLE files, which are in RLE format,
that worked located [here](http://samples.mplayerhq.hu/V-codecs/RLE/). (the clock AVI is dated 1999, and the newest file is dated 2008).

Also RLE (Run-length encoding) seems rather old, dating back to [Windows 3.x](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding)

I also think that `ffmpeg`, also no longer supports/includes `RLE`,
making it harder to install, the normal `brew install ffmpeg` will
not include `RLE`.

Comment: Does `"res\\1488.avi"` exist in the file system? Is the relative path expanding to what you think it does? (Pro tip: **Never** use relative paths. Ever)

Comment: Thank you for the question, yes the file most certainly does exist, the "std::ifstream" ensures we enter the if block. Also when replacing the file with some other RLE files I have found it works. I suspect it's the AVI files. And what I do not understand is that uncompressed files should also work, in AVI format - but I know too little about video format's to know for sure if AVI is all that is required. Perhaps I should try and find some sample online AVI files to see if they work.

Comment: AVI is not a video format. It's a file container format that can store audio and video in just about any format. Given the age of this control, you'll have to go with ancient codecs.

Comment: It's so strange that VS 2022, still has it...

I have tested the AVI files found here - AND IT WORKS!!! (phew I can work without RLE)

http://samples.mplayerhq.hu/avi/
and this one worked fine: http://samples.mplayerhq.hu/avi/verona60avi56k.avi

So it must be the tools I am using to covert the Spinner. Dang it seems so hard to find a tool that actually works.

Comment: After re-looking the AVI file mentioned above verona60...
I am using a tool called MediaArea - showing the Vide format, it says it's RLE.
Run length encoded 8bpp RGB, Codec ID 0x01000000.

Comment: I have a utility from 2003 which can probably do the conversion.  Unfortunately it was discontinued in 2008, so you can't get it yourself.  But if you can make your GIF available somewhere I could convert it for you.

Comment: Hey @MarkRansom thank for the offer. It's so kind of you. I have actually managed to get it right, by using a trial version of Adobe Media Converter. One needs to do this on a non ARM version of Windows. 
I used Windows 10, and then when you convert choose not to include metadata when converting. I found that after this I made a couple of sizes, 16x16, 24x24, 64x64 just in case. Also in the process I destroyed my one Windows installation, probably full of malware of all the junk I Installed/tried.
https://www.adobe.com/nz/products/media-encoder.html

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the animation control.
Instead please follow this tutorial [CPictureEx](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1427/Add-GIF-animation-to-your-MFC-and-ATL-projects-wit).

It works well. Good luck.